# Android sync issue: Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, bintray, jitpack

It's strange that my android project is working fine on my old laptop but on new laptop this library is not being synced. I have cleaned and rebuilt studio many times and also turned off the firewall but still it's not being synced. What should I do?Here are the lines added in my root gradle file:
`classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5'`
`classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.21.0"`

and the project is gradle base with version: 7.3.1
kotlin version is: 1.8.10
// jcenter() is already commented
this is also added:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
       
    }
}
```

I tried clean & rebuild.
I tried invalidate caches & restart.
I added path to exclusion list in windows defender and also disabled the firewall.
Deleted folder .gradle so that cashes get lost.

Comment: maybe its library compatibility ...

Library compatibility with new laptop: While unlikely, ensure the library you're using is compatible with the architecture and OS version of your new laptop. Some libraries might have specific requirements that your old laptop met but the new one doesn't.

Comment: please post also project structure?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved by adding jcenter(). Previously it was commented in gradle file.